# SQL statement for selecting information from 'next' row, last record drops off

Tags: sql, mysql, row

I'm having trouble with a select statement retrieving information from the 'next' row. I have a table in MySQL with state information (on or off), example records as below:

state table: (id is autoincrement)

```
+-----+----------+----------+---------------------+
| id  | asset_id | state_id | created             |
+-----+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 917 |       97 |        1 | 2013-10-13 22:07:03 |
| 918 |       97 |        0 | 2013-10-13 22:09:34 |
| 919 |       97 |        1 | 2013-10-13 22:09:52 |
| 924 |       97 |        0 | 2013-10-14 10:39:24 |
| 939 |       97 |        1 | 2013-10-14 12:47:26 |
| 940 |       97 |        0 | 2013-10-14 12:47:27 |
+-----+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

What I need to do is to come up with a statement that gives me state transition start and end times for each asset within a given date like this:
The endtime is always the starttime of the next state. If the last state in a day stays on until the next day, I will report that as the endtime:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| state_id | starttime           | endtime             |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        1 | 2013-10-13 22:07:03 | 2013-10-13 22:09:34 |
|        0 | 2013-10-13 22:09:34 | 2013-10-13 22:09:52 |
|        1 | 2013-10-13 22:09:52 | 2013-10-14 10:39:24 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here's my current statement:

```
SELECT t1.state_id, t1.created as starttime, t2.created as endtime 
FROM state t1, state t2 
WHERE t1.created like "2013-10-13%" and t1.asset_id=97 and t2.created = 
(SELECT min(created) FROM state 
    WHERE id > t1.id and asset_id = 97 order by created desc);
```

This works fine when the date requested is not the last day of the resultset like in the example for '2013-10-13'. The problem is the last day and the last state (last record).
if I run the example data for 2013-10-14, I get only two state transitions instead of three:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| state_id | starttime           | endtime             |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        0 | 2013-10-14 10:39:24 | 2013-10-14 12:47:26 |
|        1 | 2013-10-14 12:47:26 | 2013-10-14 12:47:27 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The last one gets dropped of presumably because the subquery's where clause 'id > t1.id'. 
The record created '2013-10-14 12:47:27' is the last one in the table and doesn't have another record after it to fetch the endtime from.

My question is:
Is it possible to change the query so that it also selects the last transition for example with a NULL as endtime like this:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| state_id | starttime           | endtime             |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        0 | 2013-10-14 10:39:24 | 2013-10-14 12:47:26 |
|        1 | 2013-10-14 12:47:26 | 2013-10-14 12:47:27 |
|        0 | 2013-10-14 12:47:27 | NULL                |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN. Try this.  You can see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9cb7/2

```
SELECT t1.state_id, t1.created as starttime, t2.created as endtime 
FROM state t1
LEFT JOIN state t2 
  ON t1.asset_id = t2.asset_id
   AND t1.created < t2.created
WHERE t1.created like "2013-10-13%" and t1.asset_id=97 
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM state
     WHERE state.created > t1.created
      AND state.created < t2.created)
ORDER BY starttime
```

Comment: Nice one AgRizzo! I would up-vote your answer as it is definitely useful, but I don't seem to have enough reputation to do so as I just joined... Anyhow, much appreciated.

Comment: I had to make one modification to your query to make it work on all data I had in the table. This includes records also for other assets than the example 97. I believe this was messing up the select for NOT EXIST and resulted in the last record dropping off if the requested date was not the last one in the table.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
and t2.created = 
(SELECT min(created) FROM state 
    WHERE id > t1.id and asset_id = 97 order by created desc);
```

to

```
and (t2.created = 
(SELECT min(created) FROM state 
    WHERE id > t1.id and asset_id = 97 order by created desc))
    or t2.created is NULL;
```

That will work unless there are other conditions that would cause t2.created to be NULL and you don't want that record - without the schema it is difficult to be sure.

Comment: I tried modifying the query with your suggested changes but no luck I'm afraid. There are no other conditions that would impact results. You could think of it as a single table database. The only reason t2.created would be NULL is when t1.id is in the last record and therefore t2 does not exist.